# Which command should run when package.json file modified?

Tags: angular, npm

I am working ona an angular project. I pushed code on git server. Another developer cloned code his own computer and run `"npm install"` to install node packages. And he pushed the code.

So the package.json file modified:

```
"tslib": "^1.9.0"  changed as  "tslib": "1.10.0"
"pify": "^2.0.0"   changed as  "pify": "2.3.0"
....
...
```

I will pull new codes on my computer. And will I run `"npm install"` again or `"npm update"` or else?

Comment: with npm install it's enough

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everytime someone add/updates/removes packages you should run `npm install` again to match your enviroment with the one described in the package.json.

**UPDATE:**

Also, this is not the whole story.

Recent versions of the npm tool also produce a file called `package-lock.json` which tells npm exactly which versionof each package it needs to install. Be sure to also put this file in your version control so that every development environment is aligned with the same versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider to use `npm ci`. It depends on your needs. On our team, one member is responsible for the `package.json` and `package-lock.json`.

So he is useing `npm install`. If you have packages taged with `~` or `^`, new versions will be downloaded. He is doeing the work to check if the new version of a package will not break some code.

Other team member just use `npm ci` to install the exact versions of the packages that are written in `package-lock.json`

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ci.html